# Sylius get TaxCategory from ShippingMethod

Tags: symfony, oop, sylius

To get simple I want to call a method of a child class on a parent class.

Sylius get two interfaces for one model: `Shipping\Model\ShippingMethodInterface` is the parent interface and I will use the term of `BaseShippingMethodInterface`. `Core\Model\ShippingMethodInterface` extends of the parent interface. This interface add some methods including the `getTaxCategory()` one.

My problem is that I got an object of type `Shipping\Model\ShipmentInterface` and this object have a method call `getMethod()`. But this method return an instance of `Shipping\Model\ShippingMethodInterface` and not `Core\Model\ShippingMethodInterface` so I can't call the `getCategory()` method on this object.

If someone know how to bypass this conception problem let me know.

Thank you

Comment: despite of interface inheritance, did you tried simply call and debug value of `$shippingMethod->getTaxCategory()`?

Comment: Not yet because I can't call my function for the moment, I have to override lot of stuff before, but my IDE couldn't autocomplete this method. I found a temporary solution but not really good. I declared my class as a service and passed the shippingMethodRepository as argument. Then I find the the correspondant `ShippingMethod` and use the `getTaxCategory()` method on the right object